# Windows 10 connection to fileserver stops working after a few minutes

Tags: windows, network-share

I'm working with 2 Windows 10 instances on the same computer (via hard drive swapping):  Windows 10 Enterprise, and a Windows 10 DOD SHB.  This machine is on an isolated developer network with no outside connections.  The problem that I'm having is trying to access a windows server file share on the network.  On my stock Windows Enterprise system, all works well.  The problem is with my SHB instance where DNS and ping are not working.

The problems started with ping by hostname was not resolving the name, as well with trying to connect to the file share by hostname.  Ping by ip address works, as well as connecting to the fileshare by ip addess (although other issues remain).  I ended up turning on network discovery and file sharing on my client machine.  This allows it resolve hostnames after a reboot, but it stops working after a few minutes.

When I do manage to connect to the file share, I'm able to provide correct credentials to it (by using an account on the server itself), but it doesn't display any of the shared folders.  If I type in the full address to a shared folder, nothing is displayed or it can't find it.

I have grabbed a copy of the %systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions from both systems and compare them.  While there is changes, nothing is slapping me in the face at the moment.

Edit:  Remote Desktop to the fileserver works fine, but only by IP address.

Edit:  Both instances have the same network settings, ipconfig gets the same data from both.  Hosts files have not been changed and are identical.

Edit:  Tried to add the fileserver in the Hosts file.  It doesn't resolve any issues with the fileserver.

Comment: So troubleshoot DNS on the client. Share your IP settings, and what happens when you do a resolve-DNSname from the client. Have you also checked your HOSTS file?

Comment: I see you swap 2 HDD, does the computer are the same on both image ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 one image is stock Windows 10 Enterprise, works perfectly.  The other is the SHB version which I am having problems.  I did find that STIG V-70639 was keeping me from the file server.  I would set that as the answer, but I'm not certain if there other things I can try to do it properly.

Comment: My typo sorry, I mean computer **name** are the same on both OS install?

Comment: @yagmoth555 yes, the computer name is the same for both systems.  It is set by our disk imaging system.

Comment: Please set a new name then to make a test, I think your issue is there, as if in an AD that mess with computer account ssid not mactching pc account (only if you have an ad in that isolated environnement)